# How do i connect other devices with OPENVPN

Tags: raspberry-pi, vpn

I haveused VPNBOOK.com to get myself free vpn on my raspberry pi 4, and it is working on my raspberry, now I want to use it with other devices. such as my laptop, phone etc.

I'm wondering if i have to keep the terminal open on my raspberry, in order for it to keep the vpn going?
everytime i close it, my vpn shuts down, but when the terminal is open the vpn is open. I assume i need to have this terminal open.

My other question is, how do i connect other devices to this vpn? I cannot find anything helpfull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using openvpn, add '--daemon' option to your cmd line, like this.

`sudo openvpn --daemon --cd /etc/openvpn --config VPNConfig.ovpn --log-append /var/log/openvpn.log`

if you are using other vpn, you can put it to background by adding a '&' to the end of your cmd line,like 
`vpn_cmd -params &`

another approach is you can use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/installing.html) to run the task for you.
maybe you can post your commands here so others can help you.

> My other question is, how do i connect other devices to this vpn? I cannot find anything helpfull?

you can setup a [privoxy](https://www.privoxy.org/) on your rpi and connect other device via http proxy